# Barbara, Celarent, Darii, et Ferio. Whom devised the vowel-consonant designations?

Tags: philosophy

In the history of philosophy & logic there is a taxonomy of syllogisms designated by name. William of Sherwood and Peter of Spain write of a mnemonic to help medieval students of logic memorize the syllogisms:

> Barbara celarent darii ferio baralipton
>   Celantes dabitis fapesmo frisesomorum;
>   Cesare campestres festino baroco; darapti
>   Felapton disamis datisi bocardo ferison.

Vowels & particular consonants have particular meaning.

- a – universalis affirmativa (i.e. **a**ffirmo)
- e – universalis negativa (i.e. n**e**go)
- i – particularis affirmativa (i.e. aff**i**rmo)
- o – particularis negativa (i.e. neg**o**)
- s – conversio **s**implex.
- p – conversio **p**er accidens.
- c – reductio ad **c**ontradictionem
- m – **m**etathesis (in Petrus Hispanus, conversio per contrapositionem?).
- B – reductio ad Modus **B**arbara.
- C – reductio ad Modus **C**elarent.
- D – reductio ad Modus **D**arii.
- F – reductio ad Modus **F**erio.

Whom first devised the vowel-consonant designations in the taxonomy of syllogisms?

(A link to an article describing the context of logicians naming syllogisms mnemonically: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/)

Comment: Please cite all non-trivial assertions. Please give the average reader enough information to understand the question.  Is this a history question or a linguistics question, or a philosophy question?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Comment: Awesome & upvoted. Can you include a link for those of us for whom this is completely new?

Comment: See the post [who-first-devised-the-vowel-consonant-designations-in-the-taxonomy-of-syllogisms](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/who-first-devised-the-vowel-consonant-designations-in-the-taxonomy-of-syllogisms)